# Conditions for the aggregate to be monotone

Tags: integration, monotone-functions

Let $g:X\times S \rightarrow R $  be a twice continuously differentiable function. What conditions suffice to get $G(s)=\int_X g(x,s)dx$ is monotone in $s$?

Obviously an easy one would be if $g(x, s)$ is monotone in $s$ for all $x$ but I am hoping that there are much weaker conditions out there. Feel free to make additional assumptions such as $\frac{\partial^2 g(s,x)}{\partial s \partial x} \geq 0$ etc. though I am not sure how helpful that one is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $S$ is an interval, possibly infinite, and that by "monotone" you mean nondecreasing.  Of course, for nonincreasing you can reverse the inequalities.

Assuming $g(x,s)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $s$ for every $x$, with $\partial g/\partial s \in L^1(X \times B)$ for each compact $B$ (to allow using Fubini's theorem), for $s_1 < s_2$ we have

$$ G(s_2) - G(s_1) = \int_X (g(x,s_2) - g(x,s_1))\; dx = 
\int_X \int_{s_1}^{s_2} \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial s}(x,s)\; ds\; dx
=\int_{s_1}^{s_2}  \int_X \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial s}(x,s)\; dx\; ds $$

so it suffices to have $\displaystyle \int_X \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial s}(x,s)\; dx \ge 0$ for all $s$.  On the other hand, if $\displaystyle \int_{X} \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial s}(x,s) \; dx < 0$ on some interval
$(s_1, s_2)$ we would have $G(s_2) < G(s_1)$.